# CSS ul li bullet disappear

Tags: php, html, css, html-lists

ul and li in my webpage not work at all. 
here is my index.html

```
<div id="main" class="core">
    <div id="background">       
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="default"><div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="special"></div>

</div>
```

this is my page.php

```
// Care for the Square
case 'care-for-the-square':
    echo '
    <p>On an annual basis the Friends fund: </p>
    <ul id="test">
    <li>Landscaping</li>
    <li>Tree care</li>
    <li>Grass seeding</li>
    <li>Graffiti removal</li>
    <li>Bench repair</li>
    <li>Supplemental seasonal maintenance staff</li>
    <li>Sidewalk sweeing</li>
    <li>A dedicated park ranger</li>
    <li>Excess seasonal trash removal</li>
    <li>Holiday lights</li>
    <li>Doggie bags</li>
    </ul><br/>

    ';
    break;
```

could anyone help me to figure it out ?  thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow user2434428! When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this. To help get your problem understood by other users, try adding some code to help.

Comment: It works fine on jsfiddle. Are you using any CSS file? Maybe you have overriden the default style of ul/li in your css file.

Comment: How do tou style your code? Could you provide a little more information?

Comment: I will re post the my all code   thank you guys

Comment: http://50.62.140.177/frs/index.html#care-for-the-square

Comment: above is my website,  as you see,  On an annual basis the Friends fund:  the bullet should be showed up .      this is what I mean the ul and li don't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that the `ul` is set to `list-style: none`, although it's more likely that the bullets have disappeared because the default left margin and/or padding has been removed. As noted, you need to post your CSS too, or preferably a working example that demonstrates the issue.

EDIT: In normalize.css, line 270, you have this rule:

```
menu, ol, ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

That is hiding your bullet points. You can either get rid of that second list-item rule, or override it with this:

```
#test li {list-style: disc;}
```

Comment: OK, I've edited my post with a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the bullets are not on the page, the most likely reason is your CSS setting your ul / li to

```
list-style: none;
```

I've created an example showing how it works, [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eFEs9/). A lot of sites will have a reset.css, could be called something else, which will be why these don't show up by "default". If you provide more information, like your css, the community might be able to help further.

Comment: I was about to paste my all code here, but the system said " it is about almost code , please add more detail".  I don't know what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Add in this css...

## CSS

```
ul#test li {
    margin-left:10px;
    list-style:disc;    
}
```